# Why is it that when I maximize a window the screen becomes white?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 and i installed my nVIDIA graphic driver.

Every thing is good except SOMETIMES when i maximize a window , movie , a software or whatever all screen will become white and when i double click again and in small windows it becomes like normal again.

This problem does not happen all the times, but why is that problem with maximized window?

Answer (score 1):

[290.10 driver release notes](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-290.10-driver.html)

> - Fixed a regression that caused blank/white windows when exhausting video memory on GeForce 6 and 7 series GPUs while using composited desktops.

This is a bug that was solved with the latest version of the driver, I am assuming you installed it from the `Additional Drivers` tool in Ubuntu.

It happens only when using Unity3D, Unity2D should not have this issue.

To solve this you only need to upgrade to the latest driver from nVidia. De-activate the current driver before downloading and installing the new one from the site.

As an alternative you can also add the [X Ubuntu Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) and install the `nvidia-graphics-drivers` package after de-activating the one you are using now.

If you need further information on how to install the most recent driver please drop a comment or open a new question with it for instructions even tough I am sure there is already a question about this on the AskUbuntu site, so give it a search before you do so.